# Jboss 7.1 JMS with Spring authentication error

Tags: spring, jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

I am trying to use hornetq ( jms on jboss ) using spring. But I couldn't be able to authenticate the user. It seems I am having problem with sending the user creditentials to the hornetq authentication interface. my spring config :

```
<bean id="jmsJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${jms.jndi.initialContextFactory}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${jms.jndi.providerUrl}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${jms.jndi.username}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${jms.jndi.password}</prop>                
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">${jms.jndi.packagePrefixes}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jmsJndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="${jms.connectionFactory}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jmsIletisimRawDataSendDestination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jmsJndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="${jms.iletisim.rawdata.send}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionExceptionListener" class="com.marti.jms.ConnectionExceptionListener">
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionPool" class="com.marti.jms.PoolFTConnection" init-method="initConnection" destroy-method="destroyConnection">
    <property name="cf" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="exceptionListener" ref="jmsConnectionExceptionListener"/>
    <property name="poolSize" value="${jms.poolSize}"/>           
</bean>

<bean id="iletisimRawDataSender" class="com.marti.jms.MessageSender" depends-on="jmsConnectionPool" init-method="setupSender" destroy-method="destroySender">
    <property name="connections" ref="jmsConnectionPool"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="jmsIletisimRawDataSendDestination"/>
    <property name="sessionsPerConnection" value="${jms.sessionPerConnection}"/>
    <property name="messageTTL" value="${jms.ttl}"/>
</bean>
```

Am I using something wrong ? ( obviously it is :) )

here is the stacktrace;

> 14:52:13,408 ERROR [org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.HornetQPacketHandler] (Old I/O server worker (parentId: 29291087, [id: 0x01bef24f, /0.0.0.0:5445])) Failed to create session : HornetQException[errorCode=105 message=Unable to validate user: null]
>       at org.hornetq.core.security.impl.SecurityStoreImpl.authenticate(SecurityStoreImpl.java:147) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.createSession(HornetQServerImpl.java:807) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.HornetQPacketHandler.handleCreateSession(HornetQPacketHandler.java:187) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.HornetQPacketHandler.handlePacket(HornetQPacketHandler.java:85) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.handlePacket(ChannelImpl.java:508) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.doBufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:556) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:517) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.hornetq.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:533) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.HornetQChannelHandler.messageReceived(HornetQChannelHandler.java:73) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:100) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.StaticChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(StaticChannelPipeline.java:372) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.StaticChannelPipeline$StaticChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(StaticChannelPipeline.java:534) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:287) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.HornetQFrameDecoder2.decode(HornetQFrameDecoder2.java:169) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.HornetQFrameDecoder2.messageReceived(HornetQFrameDecoder2.java:134) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:80) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.StaticChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(StaticChannelPipeline.java:372) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.StaticChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(StaticChannelPipeline.java:367) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioWorker.run(OioWorker.java:100) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:44) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at org.jboss.netty.util.VirtualExecutorService$ChildExecutorRunnable.run(VirtualExecutorService.java:181) [netty-3.2.6.Final.jar:]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_37]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a temporary or a workaround solution but whoever wants to fix this issue or doesn't wants to came across the same issue; here is the solution :

- On jboss management interface click Profile on the top right of the screen.
- Click Messaging -> Mesaging Provider on the left tree menu.
- On the right pane click "view" for the provider you are trying to connect.
- Then Edit the settings for "JMS Provider Configurations" to set Security Enabled to "false".

Comment: if you actually want to use authentication, you should've configured them with spring. I answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18874625/365237) as to how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are just getting authentication errors?

You just need to add the user and password to the user's group using the addUser script that comes with JBoss.

I would need more details (your exception stack trace for example) if you're getting a different error.

Comment: I've added the stacktrace. plus the user name and passwords are stored in a prop file which is in : <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:constants.properties,classpath:common.properties"/>